# PHP take arguments from URL path

Tags: php, url

Say I have a url like this:

`http://www.mysite.com/forum/board1/sub-forum/topics/123`

Is there a simple way in PHP (can't use HTAccess) to take that URL and extract `board1`, `sub-forum`, `topics` and `123` so I can use them in a database for example? Are there any built in functions or will I have to write my own?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
explode('/', getenv('REQUEST_URI'));
```

If your environment happens to include the query string part in the above value, here's a neat workaround:

```
explode('/', strtok(getenv('REQUEST_URI'), '?'));
```

Comment: @Gumbo It wasn't a requirement. Merging this array with $_GET isn't difficult either.

Comment: @pestaa: But *REQUEST\_URI* does not just contain the request URI path but also the query string.

Comment: @Gumbo Environment-specific, mine happens to include the URI path only. For clarity, I'll include a second snippet soon.

Comment: @Gumbo Have a look please. **Can't** be any shorter, right? :)

Comment: Sorry people - I only want the stuff after the domain address (ie `forum/board1/sub-forum/topics/123` that)

Comment: If you are thinking of using this method then, better nullify the use of query string at all and send all the values within the format of `forum/board1/sub-forum/topics/123`

Comment: I've marked this as the right answer, however @nikc has made a very good point about 404 errors. I will look into using HTAccess files and possibly mod_rewrite if I can get access to it on my server. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @JamWaffles Given the level of your question I made the assumption all requests are forwarded to a single entry point. Mere presence of the index.php won't catch all incoming URLs by default.

Comment: Thanks for that :-) I do admit my post was rather vague. What I want to do is simply replace the normal URL encoded arguments that PHP normally uses with `$_GET` with a path - it makes the URLs much cleaner.

Comment: @pestaa: Did you try a request that already contains a query string?

Comment: @JamWaffles Judging by the fact you can't use .htaccess, you're on a shared host. I suggest to switch hosting provider to gain the htaccess feature. Otherwise you can't catch incoming requests that don't contain your PHP file name! Mod_rewrite is the easiest option surely.

Comment: @Gumbo I have a running site that uses the first option. `strtok` in the second approach will return everything before the question mark. I do admit I haven't tried it in production, but hey, I bet my left leg it works!

Comment: In my case `getenv('REQUEST_URI')` has returned a path with a leading slash. I've worked around it by doing `ltrim(getenv('REQUEST_URI'), '/')`.

Answer (score 4):

You can, but without redirecting requests your webserver will just return a 404 error for non-existing paths.

However, you can use urls like `http://your.site.com/index.php/foo/bar/baz` and then split the url into parts like @pestaa said which you can then parse into parameter values.

Comment: Well, the paths are virtual - they're taken from a database and constructed. Are you saying that navigating to that path will return a 404, but still execute the PHP?

Comment: No. I mean unless your webserver will know that all urls should be redirected to a PHP script, it will look at the corresponding path on the filesystem and return a 404 error when it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks for that. I take it the solution is to use HTAccess files? I *may* be able to edit the mod_rewrite rules, but don't count on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is taken from my MVC 
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6363-PHP-Implements-the-MVC-design-pattern.html

The link is outdated at the minute, I have just updated it so it does not have the MVC stuff in, and this can be called with getLoadDetails($_URL); amd $_URL will be exactly the same as $_GET other than it gets the data from the folder path.

```
function getLoadDetails(&$_URL){
            $filePath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $filePath = explode("/", $filePath);

            for($i = 0; $i < count($filePath); $i++){
                    $key = $filePath[$i];
                    $i++;
                    $val = $filePath[$i];
                    $keyName = urldecode($key);
                    $_URL[$keyName] = urldecode($val);
            }
    }
```

I do have one question, if you cant use HTACCESS how do you plan on coping with the folder path please dont tell me your system is going to create the folder paths and index file for every URL that will trash your server Speed and your Host will hate you for it.

Comment: No no - that would be most insane! Creating all the directories is just mad. As I have mentioned in other comments, I will use HTAccess and possibly mod_rewrite. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have configured your web server to send those requests to your particular PHP file, you can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to get and then split the requested URI path into its segments:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathSegments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
```