# How to get php url with no parameters

Tags: php

I have big problem. I have some code like :
This is in my folder "country"

```
if($_GET[''] == 'England') {
    echo 'test';
}
```

Is that impossible to left empty get parameter? to get url like : link.com/country/England

Comment: Look up "htaccess rewrites".

Comment: Check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213946/php-take-arguments-from-url-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following: `example.com/country/?England`, and check if the `England` key exists:

```
 if(isset($_GET['England'])) {
       // Do stuff
 }
```

Without the `?` characters, it's a bit more difficult and require to rewrite URL with `[mod_rewrite][1]` if you're using Apache web server for example

Comment: Ok, but without "?" ...

Comment: Response updated... You should read the documentation and try by yourself before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for url rewriting: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html