# Is there a way to retreive $_GET content from a modified url

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I am trying to make my URL's tidy.
Here is my original URL:
`https://example.com/cssgzip.php?file=/assets/css/main.css`
I have made it look like this:
`https://example.com/cssgzip/assets/css/main.css`

I used this to remove the `.php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Like this:
`https://example.com/cssgzip?file=/assets/css/main.css`

I used this to remove `?file=`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ cssgzip.php?file=$1
```

Like this:
`https://example.com/cssgzip/assets/css/main.css`

But now, when I run `$_GET['file']` on `https://example.com/cssgzip/assets/css/main.css`, nothing comes back.

I tried `$_REQUEST['file']` and that is empty too.

Is there something I am doing wrong? What can I do instead?

Comment: Essentially you want to parse values from the URL route.  There could be more updated ways of doing that these days, especially with the variety of frameworks available.  But a simple approach could just be to parse the URL itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213946/php-take-arguments-from-url-path

Answer (score 0):

By removing `?file=`, your remove the value declaration of the `file` variable, so `$_GET['file']` has no value. For example, if you manually change the value of `?file=` in the url, it will also change the value of the variable.

If you use the GET method, you will need to have that in the url. Otherwise, use POST.